# Is there a complete and list of the different actions one user can see of another?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, recent-activity, privacy

After being around Stack Overflow for about two months, I find myself looking through lots of other peoples' profiles/activity to see if there is anything else I can learn from one of their old questions/answers.

This got me wondering if some sort of bullet list exists that shows every single action one can see about another user. I'm *almost* certain I know all the different public parts of an account, but it would be interesting to discover something I didn't know about.

*Does such a list exist?*

---

For example, the list would be something like:

**Action**           -  **Is Public**

- "comments"   -   YES
- "answers"      -   YES
- "flags"            -   NO
- "questions"    -   YES
- etc...

Answer (score 4):

Check this site [http://data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=favorite) with very useful statistics

There you can see a lot of different statistics such as:

- [My Top-ranked comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/945/my-top-ranked-comments) (I found that you have 2 comments with 3 up-vote ;)
- [Users with more than 10 duplicate accounts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/88/users-with-more-than-10-duplicate-accounts)
- [Compare me against the most frequent voters](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/570/compare-me-against-the-most-frequent-voters)

Your id you can find at your personal page in top-right corner: `user:XXXXXX`

Comment: Your profile icon plays tricks on my eyes!  It looks like its pulsating on my dimly lit laptop screen! :)

Comment: I've played around with data.se a bunch already, but what I really want to know is if there is a FAQ-like page that lists all of the different *types* of publicly available user info there is.  For example, the list would just contain a list like:  "comments - YES", "answers - YES", "flags - NO", "questions - YES", etc.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

> This got me wondering if some sort of bullet list exists that shows every single action one can see about another user.

The [Stack Exchange network profile activity list](https://stackexchange.com/users/66276?tab=activity) shows just about all publicly available activity done throughout the network.

Comment: I've seen that, but what I want to know is if there is a FAQ-like page that lists all of the different kinds of public info about someone.  For example, the list would just contain a list like:  "comments - YES", "answers - YES", "flags - NO", "questions - YES", etc.  Does that make sense?